# Can "to fly on" be used to mean "to land"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Can "to fly on" be used to mean "to land"?

Here are two examples:

> **(1)** "The Navy has traversed a long and complicated road in trying to
> develop a UAS that would **fly on and off** its aircraft carriers." [[source]](https://www.defensenews.com/naval/2018/08/30/us-navy-selects-builder-for-new-mq-25-stingray-aerial-refueling-drone/)
>
> **(2)** "It was not only a question of life or death for Lt. Shannon Workman,
> at the controls, but also a question of whether the Navy was right or
> wrong in allowing women to **fly on and off** aircraft carriers in combat
> planes [...]" [[source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/1994/11/08/aboard-the-uss-dwight-d-eisenhower/886d0e5b-22dc-44a7-bd5a-52394cb9fe49/?utm_term=.36ed894a9f48)]

I couldn't find a dictionary entry for the idiom "fly on", so given the examples above, I'd like to know if it really means "to land", or maybe it has some more nuanced meaning.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I believe that those articles are using uncommon prepositions in this context. More commonly, it would be *fly **onto** and **off of** aircraft carriers.* And *to land*, while very closely related, doesn't mean precisely the same thing as the first. (But you could say that it does, effectively, in this case.) Still, the wording here is unusual.

Comment: I guess *land on and take off from* was too wordy. But there is also a subtle difference in point of view. As written, the point of view is firmly with the aircraft.

Comment: According to [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_Naval_Air_Stations) the USNAF operates aircraft from both ships and land based airfields. I suggest that the quotes refer to Unmanned Aerial Systems (UAS) and female pilots operating both from ships (flying on ships) and from airfields (flying off ships)

Comment: _On and off_ is a constituent all by itself. If it's talking about aircraft flying on and off an aircraft carrier, it can only mean they land on and take off from it.

Comment: As John Lawler states, it's specifically referring to *on and off* of a naval aircraft carrier, where "on and off" is a compound preposition and "aircraft carriers" is the object of those prepositions.  "Fly on", by itself, and absent an appropriate object for the preposition, is not grammatical.